# How to take id value and add it grandparent as an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone first post here and I'm working on a navigation bar and needed to add and id and value to the ul, then in an anchor tag above it, add an attribute of aria-controls = the value of the id I made for the ul.

```
<li class="hs-menu-item hs-menu-depth-1 hs-item-has-children" role="menu">
<a href="https://www.website.org/"  aria-expanded="false">Rates</a>
<a class="child-trigger"><span></span></a>
<ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper">
```

So far I've added the id and added the attribute with Javascript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hs-menu-children-wrapper")[0].setAttribute("id","Rates");
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[10].setAttribute("aria-controls","Rates");
```

which gave me what I wanted.

```
<a href="https://www.website.org" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Rates">Rates</a>
<a class="child-trigger"><span></span></a>
<ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper" id="Rates" >
```

but I have 5 other elements with id's that I need to apply this to and targeting the different anchor tags won't work for every page we plan to use this with. I pretty much need help simplifying this thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but let me back you up a few steps.... Both `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByClassName()` are very old APIs that both return "live" node sets, which have performance implications and are only right for particular use cases. Worse still, you've got `document.getElementsByClassName("hs-menu-children-wrapper")[0]`, which will scan the entire DOM every time you reference that node list and then it will throw away all the elements it finds because you are only asking for the first one. .....

Comment: ....This is a big waste. Instead, use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which allows you to pass any valid CSS selector in and get a static node list.  Lastly, I have to ask why are you focusing on setting an `id` in the first place. Building solutions around `id`s is usually not a  scaleable way to go. Can't you just get the `ul` reference based on its position within your code?

Comment: When's that code being called? after some event?  why do you say it won't work on everypage? what's the difference on those pages? which of the A tags does `getElementsByTagName("a")[10]` target? you can use `ul.previousSibling` to move from the ul to the `a.child-trigger` for example. Also, from the code you show, the li is the parent of the ul, not the grandparent.

Comment: I want the code to be called when the page loads and sorry what I meant by it not working on every page was that we only have this navigation bar on our main pages but on our blog pages we don't use it so my manager didn't want it targeting other A tags on those pages.

Comment: We have an auditor looking at our website for accessibility and adding the id to those elements was one of the things we were required to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming each is contained in its own parent element, something like this could work. Of course, you'd want to give the trigger `a` some sort of class to identify and hook into.

```js
/**
 * First, we create a list of all the uls we want to connect.
 *  Note that, because some browsers don't treat a list of 
 *  nodes as an Array, we want to convert it to an array.
 *  Here, I'm using the ES6 spread operator, which may not be
 *  the best option, but for demonstration purposes, it works.
 **/
const ulEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul")];

/**
 * Now, iterate over that array. With each ul, we want to find
 *  a parent element, and then within that, locate the anchor
 *  that will be made the control for this ul. Once we find
 *  that, we can assign it the attribute with the value we want.
 **/
ulEls.forEach( (ulEl) => {
  let container = ulEl.parentNode,
      triggerEl = container.querySelector(".ul-controller");
      triggerEl.setAttribute("aria-controls", ulEl.id);
} );
```

```html
<div>
  <a class='ul-controller' href="https://www.website.org" aria-expanded="false">Rates</a>
  <a class="child-trigger"><span></span></a>
  <ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper" id="Rates" >
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <a class='ul-controller' href="https://www.website.org" aria-expanded="false">Sizes</a>
  <a class="child-trigger"><span></span></a>
  <ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper" id="Sizes" >
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <a class='ul-controller' href="https://www.website.org" aria-expanded="false">Times</a>
  <a class="child-trigger"><span></span></a>
  <ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper" id="Cheezburger" >
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you open the console, you'll see that the `aria-controls` is being set on each dynamically. Basically, it iterates over each `ul`, and uses that as the starting point for setting its sibling `a` to the appropriate `aria-controls` using `setAttribute()`.

EDIT: As was pointed out, `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList, which not every browser will treat as an Array. So it is best practice to convert that into an array before trying to run `forEach` over the set.

Comment: Just one comment... `querySelectorAll()` returns a node list and `.forEach()` doesn't work on node lists in all browsers. It's a best practice to convert the node list to an array first and then call `.forEach()` on that array.

Comment: True point. I'll edit that. See what I get for developing on chrome? I've become a code snob. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed and thank you everyone else for all the other input I still have a lot to learn but I learned a bit breaking down this code.